# Permutation and Combination to find pairs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In how many different ways students can be paired such that no pair consists of 2 boys. Given :- Total students = 10, Girls = 7, boys = 3.

What my approach is 3 boys can be paired with 7 girls like G1B1,G2B1,G3B1 etc.which gives 21 ways.Not sure if this is true.

Answer given :630

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boy1 can be paired with any one of $7$ girls. For each such choice, Boy2 can be paired with any one of $6$ girls, and Boy3 with any one of $5$ girls. The remaining girls can be divided into pairs in $3$ ways, for a total of $(7)(6)(5)(3)$.

To see that the remaining $4$ girls can be paired in $3$ ways, let one of the remaining girls be Alicia. She can choose her partner in $3$ ways.

Comment: Won't there be a + sign between 7,6,5,3?

Comment: No, it is multiplication.  For **each** of the $7$ ways of finding a girl partner for Boy1, there are $6$ ways to deal with Boy2, so $(7)(6)$ ways of finding girl partners for Boy1 and Boy2.  And so on.